# Validar Login com Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou com um problema no metodo de validar o loguin, ele está logando tanto com o login e senha certo como com eles errados.
Quando ele loga com o login errado o id do usuario vai como 0
e se ele loga com os dados corretos o id vai 1
como ajeito?

```
    public Usuario validarLogin(String login, String senha) {

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{login, senha};
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from usuarios where login=? and senha=?", selectionArgs);
    Usuario usuarioLinha = new Usuario();
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        usuarioLinha.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_usuario")));
        usuarioLinha.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
        usuarioLinha.setLogin(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("login")));
        usuarioLinha.setSenha(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("senha")));
    }
    return usuarioLinha;
}
```

Comment: E o que era pra acontecer no caso de usuário ou senha errada?

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho como saber qual o retorno executado pós esse código, mas provavelmente está checando se o usuário é diferente de `null`, eu faria a seguinte alteração:

```
Usuario usuarioLinha;
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        usuarioLinha = new Usuario()
        usuarioLinha.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_usuario")));
        usuarioLinha.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
        usuarioLinha.setLogin(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("login")));
        usuarioLinha.setSenha(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("senha")));
    }
    return usuarioLinha;
```

Movendo a instanciação para dentro do cursor, caso o db não retorne nada, o usuário será `null`, portanto o login é inválido.

Comment: Deu certo =D vlwww